# Refresh in jquery mobile with Cordova

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, page-refresh

I am building a mobile app using apache cordova and query mobile.
I have a single page in my app.
I have a form on the page that contains a list of checkboxes and 2 buttons.

**The behaviour I need is the following.**
When I select an item in the list and click on the 'Complete' button, I want the **page/form** to refresh. By refresh, I mean that I want to call a rest service to get a new list (the same rest service that I call when the page loads for the first time), construct an html list, and then display that in the form. 
**This is what I have tried**
In the **app.initialize** I call a rest service using ajax to retrieve a list of items, construct a html list and then insert it into the form.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
    // CALL TO MY FUNCTION TO GET THE LIST OF ITEMS
    myapp.loadItems();
},
// rest of the auto generated code.
};
```

As seen above I load the list by calling loadItems which calls the rest api. The code for this is given below.

```
loadItems: function() {
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/WebApp/rsapi/items';
        $.ajax({url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var itemList = constructHtmlListItems(data);
                $('#total-num-items').val(items.length);
                $(itemsList).insertAfter( "#total-num-items" );
                $('#items-list-form').trigger("create")
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Unable to connect to server.");
            }
        });
}
```

I have overridden the default form submit behaviour, so when I click on the button I use the **onsumbit** event on the form. I call the rest service, trigger a refresh. The problem is that the screen flickers, I see the new list for a brief moment and then I see the empty form with just the buttons on it.

The function that handles the form submit is shown below.

```
refreshPage: function() {
/*$.mobile.changePage(
        window.location.href,
        {
            allowSamePageTransition : true,
            transition              : 'none',
            showLoadMsg             : false,
            reloadPage              : true
        }
        );*/
        loadItems();
        //$('#items-list-form').trigger("refresh")
        //.trigger('create');
        return false;
}
```

Please note in the above function you will see some commented code I have shown it here just to show you the various options I have tried.

**What am I doing wrong?** 
The list shows up the first time I start the app. Thereafter when I click on the button I see is an empty form, with out the dynamically constructed list. 
**How do I fix this? How do I achieve a refresh?**

Comment: we can't help you if you don't supply any code.

Comment: I have added code now.

Comment: Can you remove the unwanted comment lines and add the code with overall logic?

Comment: There aren't that many comments and I have explained the reason for them. I have editted the question and tried to word it better.

Comment: is this issue solved
because i'm facing the same issue now
ajax is not working